# jQuery code critque

Tags: javascript, jquery

Thought I'd post here. My first hour on jQuery, actually first programing ever done. Would love to learn whats not right and how it could be better.

```
$(function() {

function hide_me()
//A place to specify which elements you want hidden, on page load.
{
    $("li.credentials").hide();

}
function first_bow()
//The div right_column takes a bow on initial load.
{
    $("div#right-column").show("drop");

}
function bigpeek()
//The third column toggles in/out. All elements under div right_column.
{
    $("div#right-column").toggle("drop", "fast");

}

function smallpeek()
//Smaller snippets like credentials or user assignment flying in/out.
{
    $("li.credentials").toggle("drop", "fast");

}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("*").ready(hide_me);
    $("*").ready(first_bow);
    $(".btn-new-email").click(bigpeek);
    $(".button").click(smallpeek);
    $(".icon-delete").mouseover(function() {
        $(this).effect("bounce", "fast");
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Maybe try this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know it existed. Will use that for the next run.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to learn about programming is how to effectively re-use code.  In your code, you have set up some functions that you yourself claim will do a bunch of the same thing.  So instead, you could make it better by only writing code to do the repeated task once.

For one example, instead of creating a function where you place a bunch of things that need to be hidden, I would add a class to the elements that should be hidden, and then hide all those elements:

```
function hide_me()
//Hides anything with the "hide-me-onload" class
{
    $(".hide-me-onload").hide();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Sean. Is that a CSS class?

Comment: @DSM - yes, but there doesn't have to be any CSS rules defined for it.  Often, when using jQuery, you'll assign non-existent css classes to your DOM elements to serve as markers and/or state.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function () {
 ...
}
```

is the same as

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 ...
}
```

So you can move the method calls from inside your $(document).ready() to be inside your $(function(){}). Also try to use IDs instead of class names wherever possible. Something like this will go through the entire DOM to look for an element

```
$(".item")
```

Be more specific

```
$("#itemID") // use IDs instead of Classes
//If you have to use class name then you can speed up the selector by adding the element tag before it
$("div.item")
```

Comment: $(function () {
 ...
}
is not even close to 

$(document).ready(function() {
 ...
}
First is a method call right after the method is loaded into browser; the second is running after the whole page is loaded.

Comment: damn, I didn't know that! +1. Can you edit your answer so I can change my vote on it? It locked my vote unless you change it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `$("*").ready()` within `$(document).ready()` is redundant...  you already know using all of the elements are ready!  Also, in general using the universal selector `$('*')` is very inefficient.

So, the first two lines of your `$(document).ready()` can just be:

```
hide_me();
first_bow();
```

Other than that and a couple of issues with organization and nomenclature you're off to a great start, keep it up!